# How to get input to a string that does not terminate with a space?

Tags: c++, string, input, cout, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

 vector<string>Games;
 vector<string>::iterator iter;
 string command;
 string name;


cin>>command;
if(command=="add"){
    cout<<"You have choosen to add a game to your backlog.\n";
    cout<<"Enter the name of the Video Game\n";
    getline(cin,name); 
    Games.push_back(name);
    cout<<"The Game has been added\n";
}
```

}

Yes, I know this has been archived. And I know you are supposed to use the getline() function passing into the function the cin and the name of the string to hold the characters, but when I compile and run this after typing the "add" command then the line
getline(cin,name) is skipped and I cannot enter anything.

Comment: Search the site for "getline skipped". I guarantee you'll find tons. Alternatively, look at the related links to the right. They look really related.

Comment: Got it, thanks I should really search more before I post. Turns out I had to include the line cin.ignore(); before taking the user input for the name. Could someone explain what this line does?

Comment: [*Extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and including delim.*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore "Reference")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before

```
getline(cin,name);
```

use

```
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

To use this statement you need include header `<limits>`